# Filter Array based on the selection of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two arrays, one contains the Min-Prices and the other contains the Max-Prices, and if the user chooses a min-price of say "8000" from the Min-price dropdown, I want to show only the values that is greater than "8000" in the Max-Price dropdown.

How can I approach that with Angular.js?

Here's a JSFiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/sheko_elanteko/fxkSz/10/

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <form action="#">
        <label>Min Price</label>
        <select name="min-price">
            <option ng-repeat="num in minPrice" value="{{ num }}">{{ num }}</option>
        </select>

        <br>

        <label>Max Price</label>
        <select name="max-price">
            <option ng-repeat="num in maxPrice" value="{{ num }}">{{ num }}</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the js ...

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){

$scope.minPrice = [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000];
$scope.maxPrice = [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000];

});
```

Comment: I would start by creating some test data and test code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that you can play around and have something to reference when you have a specific question.

Comment: I just started learning Angular, and I can't seem to get my head around it just yet. So, I have no idea how to approach this issue.

Comment: Ok, but you can create test data and HTML dropdowns and any required CSS, you know that right? And add the angular library and make an attempt, all on jsFiddle.

Comment: I made a fiddle and edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c64hJ/) that solves your problem. Its a pretty simple use of `ngRepeat` & `$scope`, and that is all.

Adding the code, as suggested

The JS part is;

```
var app = angular.module('App', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.mins = [100, 200, 300, 400];
    $scope.maxs = [200, 300, 400, 500];

    $scope.getMxRange = function () {
        var arr = [];
        if ($scope.minVal) {
            angular.forEach($scope.maxs, function (maxVal) {
                if ($scope.minVal < maxVal) {
                    this.push(maxVal);
                }
            }, arr);
        }
        else {
            arr = $scope.maxs;
        }
        return arr;
    };
}]);
```

And ofcourse, the HTML looks something like;

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="minVal">
        <option ng-repeat="min in mins" value="{{min}}">{{min}}</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="max in getMxRange()" value="{{max}}">{{max}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I believe the code is pretty self explanatory. The `ngModel` `minVal` contains the selected minimum value. and the `getMxRange` method returns all values in `maxs` which are greater than the value of the selected option in the range of minimum values.

Comment: Please don't rely on links. Post the code in your answer, along with explanations as to how it works.